# Building an interior partition wall

Tags: drywall, walls, partition

I would like to build a partition wall in my completed basement. The wall will run half the width of the room so it won’t create a new room. I plan to hang a 65” TV on the wall. The wall will run between 2 ceiling joists and parallel to them. I have received 3 estimates for the work. Two contractors say they need to install ceiling blocking or move the wall where it is under one of the joists. One contractors argues that it is not a load bearing wall and it is perfectly acceptable to attach it to the ceiling drywall using drywall anchors. The base plate will be anchored to the concrete floor.

We will all agree that anchoring to a joist or blocking is the best approach but is it acceptable to anchor to the ceiling drywall as joist or ceiling attachment is overkill in this instance? Should I discount this estimate because it’s not an acceptable approach? Does GA code specify any requirements or do they only apply if a new room is created from the partition wall?

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Anchoring to ceiling drywall is absolutely not acceptable; you need structural members to be fastened to structural members. Fastening it to drywall is not structurally sound; especially if you replace the drywall in the future, you cut away existing drywall and leave the wall only attached to the drywall above it, which is not attached to anything. Drywall is cheap; walls falling over and damaging/killing persons and/or property is not. Leaving this as a comment since I don't have specific code sections to cite for you. Georgia uses the IBC for general construction codes, btw.

Comment: I think if you want a wall that will move sure attach it to the sheetrock. I would not touch the slip shod construction company because there motto is love it or shove it. Do it right blocking or move the wall a foot.